# Why/How does the array in retain its initialized values even after slicing & mutating?

Tags: arrays, go

I'm going through the basics of go, found this in the tour [here](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/11).

I don't understand why the array values are not 0 or nil after `s = s[:0]`

```
func main() {
    s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    printSlice(s)

    // Slice the slice to give it zero length.
    s = s[:0]
    printSlice(s)

    // Extend its length.
    s = s[:4]
    printSlice(s)

    // Drop its first two values.
    s = s[2:]
    printSlice(s)
}

func printSlice(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
}
```

output :

```
len=6 cap=6 [2 3 5 7 11 13]
len=0 cap=6 []
len=4 cap=6 [2 3 5 7]
len=2 cap=4 [5 7]
```

Comment: Slice expressions do not mutate the backing array.

Comment: See https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro for an explanation of the way slices work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slice is a view on an array. A slice will only create a new larger array and copy contents if the capacity is exceeded. A slice will continue using its original array if you truncate it. When you create a smaller slice, it is still using the old backing array with the contents leftover from the previous operations. When you append to that slice, it will continue using the same array until you exceed capacity.

Comment: The same variable is re assigned right? 
I understand slice is a copy, but if `s` is an array and later `s` is assigned a slice, is it referencing a hidden pointer of all stored values?

Comment: `s` is a slice, not an array. A slice contains a pointer to an array, size and cap. The array `s` is pointing to has all the values, and unless you append to `s` so that `s` exceeds cap, the same array is used through all slice operations.

Comment: Got it! If `s := [6]int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}` here `s` would be array and I cannot assign `s = s[:0]`